# clCreateBuffer() allocating on the CPU?

Tags: c++, memory, opencl, gpu, memory-bandwidth

I'm working with a (recurrent) neural network on C++ & OpenCL to get some low-level experience with deep learning. Right now I have a simple forward propagation kernel that's yielding oddly low performance; the setup is memory limited as are most deep learning setups, and based on some crude profiling the memory bandwidth that I'm getting is around 2 GB/s. A call to clGetDeviceInfo() confirms that I'm using my onboard GPU (GTX 960m); I suspect that somehow the memory I'm allocating with clCreateBuffer() is somehow ending up on the CPU which would lead to transfer rates hovering around 2 GB/s as suggested by [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/122405/Part-2-OpenCL-Memory-Spaces). The buffers I'm allocating shouldn't be too large for the GPU; the largest are 1024*1024*4 bytes = 4 MB (weights) and only 12 of those are created.

The calls to clCreateBuffer(), with some context:

```
NVector::NVector(int size) {
    empty = false;
    numNeurons = size;
    activationsMem = clCreateBuffer(RNN::clContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * numNeurons, NULL, NULL);
    parametersMem = clCreateBuffer(RNN::clContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * numNeurons, NULL, NULL);
    derivativesMem = clCreateBuffer(RNN::clContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * numNeurons, NULL, NULL);
}

//...

void NVector::connect(NVector& other) {
    int numWeights = other.numNeurons * numNeurons;
    cl_mem weightMem = clCreateBuffer(RNN::clContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * numWeights, NULL, NULL);

    float weightAmplitude = 0.2f;
    float* weightData = new float[numWeights];
    for (int i = 0; i < numWeights; i++) {
        weightData[i] = ((rand() % 256) / 256.0f - 0.5f) * weightAmplitude;
    }

    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(RNN::clQueue, weightMem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * numWeights, weightData, 0, NULL, NULL);

    connections.push_back(&other);
    weightsMem.push_back(weightMem);
}
```

What are some reasons that OpenCL might allocate memory to the CPU instead of the active device? What can I do to force memory to be allocated on the GPU?

EDIT: a simple test yielded this value for memory bandwidth, which is in accordance with the suggested 5-6 GB/s bandwidth between the CPU and GPU.

```
operating device name: GeForce GTX 960M
2.09715 seconds
1.00663e+10 bytes
4.8e+09 bytes / second
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Can you show the call to `clCreateBuffer( ... )` specifically the flags?

Comment: @RichardCritten added that in, whoops!

Comment: can you check what pci-e mode it is running while working? pci-e 4x maybe?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik according to GPU-Z, the connection is PCI-E 2.0 x16 and actively runs at that configuration during acceleration, even without mains power.

Comment: @LukasPalmer than it should reach 5-6 GB /s using ALLOC_HOST_PTR or USE_HOST_PTR instead of being stuck at 2GB for single copy single kernel. You aren't using buffer more than once I guess(such as training iterations(epoch?) ==1 for each enqueuewritebuffer ?)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I ran a test and got numbers in accordance with that, I put that in an edit at the bottom. Grr, looks like the memory really is being held on the CPU.

Comment: @LukasPalmer then you should disable shared memory from bios so your buffers don't end up in ram. Or you may try to have a big buffer so it is allocated on video ram? Or use it repeatedly and maybe driver sends it to vram automagically? You should try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129078/discussion-between-lukas-palmer-and-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik).